# C# Spoof process owner

Tags: c#, user-interface, spoofing

Is it possible in C# to spoof the owner of a process? Lets say my process name is "Game.exe", when the user runs it, it shows up in process list as Game.exe UsernameHere

Is it possible to spoof that UsernameHere part?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into identity impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

Only by running it as a different user.